# Unhandled runtime error c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, runtime

```
 private void SetConnection(string id, string classCode)
    {
        try
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = Settings.Default.CurrentConnection };
            _connection.Open();
            while (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting || _connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            _command = new SqlCommand(Settings.Default.EligibilityBenefitSP, _connection);
            if (_command != null) _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _command.Parameters.Add("@ClassCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = classCode;
            _command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message + " " + Settings.Default.EligibilityBenefitSP);
        }

    }

   public Collection<EligibilityClassBenefit> ExtractEligibilityClassBenefit(string id, string classCode)
    {
        SetConnection(id, classCode);
        Collection<EligibilityClassBenefit> eclassBene = new Collection<EligibilityClassBenefit>();
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            _command.CommandTimeout = 420;
            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                reader = _command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            else
                throw new Exception("Connection Closed");

                /* no data */
                if (!reader.HasRows) return null;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EligibilityClassBenefit eligibilityClassBenefit = new EligibilityClassBenefit
                    {
                        EffectiveDate                = reader["EffectiveDate"].ToString(),
                        EndDate                      = reader["EndDate"].ToString(),
                        InitialEffectiveDate         = reader["InitialEffectiveDate"].ToString(),
                        IsAdministrativeServicesOnly = reader["IsAdministrativeServicesOnly"].ToString(),
                        EffectiveProvision           = reader["EffectiveProvision"].ToString(),
                        ProbationPeriod              = reader["ProbationPeriod"].ToString(),
                        UnderwritingType             = ExtractUnderwritingType(id),
                        ProbationPeriodUnit          = reader["ProbationPeriodUnit"].ToString(),
                        StateOfIssue                 = reader["StateOfIssue"].ToString(),
                    };
                    BenefitData benefitData = new BenefitData();
                    eligibilityClassBenefit.Benefit = benefitData.ExtractBenefit(reader, id, classCode);

                    EligibilityClassBenefitBusinessLevelData eligibilityLevelData = new EligibilityClassBenefitBusinessLevelData();
                    eligibilityClassBenefit.EligibilityClassBenefitBusinessLevelNodes = eligibilityLevelData.ExtractBenefitBusinessLevel(reader);

                    eclassBene.Add(eligibilityClassBenefit);
            }
            return eclassBene;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.InnerException.Message + e.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            //if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Close();
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
            _command.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Above is an example of code that has a general exception catch in it, yet when i run this program, it will randomly break and thow and unhandled exception to the application log with a .net runtime error null reference exception.

A little background...this is a console application that runs automatically at midnight on an application server. It executes stored procedures against a different SQL Server 2008 box. We used to get these errors when the connections were dropped by the sql server when doing a mainenace task, that is no longer the case. I need to get a mmore specific error. I don't understand why its bypassing the catch clause and just throwing an unhandled runtime exception. What does this mean? It happens at any number of points of code, not just this one. this is just an example of the last that blew up

Comment: What's catching the exceptions you're throwing?

Comment: can you please post the stacktrace of the unhandled exception, but looking at your code I think the NullReferenceException probably comes from one of the reader[****].ToString() Statements

Comment: You are catching an exception and throwing an other. Can you post the full error message plus stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are catching exception, you are also throwing them out to be handled by the caller. Now, there is no entry point in the code you've posted so it's hard to see what's going on outside this snippet.

However, taking a wild guess, my suggestion for origin of the NullRef exception is where you do this: `e.InnerException.Message`.

The `InnerException` property may well be null and that will cause a NullRef exception. That, however, is not the real exception. The real exception, which caused the program to end up in the exception handler is hidden because of the above mistake.

If you want to include the message from the InnerException, first check if it's null or not.

**EDIT:**

Doing this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(e.InnerException.Message + e.InnerException.StackTrace);
}
```

Catches any exception and **rethrows** it out to be handled. If the calling code is not handling exceptions, ie not wrapped the call in a try-catch block, the exception will be treated as unhandled by the runtime.

Actually, there is no point at all to do what you are doing. Don't catch exceptions unless you intend to do something about the problem. What you do here is simply messing up the StackTrace for the caller since you are rethrowing a **new** exception. If you feel you have to cut in and rethrow for some reason, you should do this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("I have a good reason for interrupting the flow", e);
}
```

Note that the exception instance is passed in the constructor for the rethrown exception. That will end up as the inner exception.

About your exception strategy, this is also pretty unnecessary:

```
if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    reader = _command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
else
    throw new Exception("Connection Closed");
```

The `ExecuteReader` method already throws an `InvalidOperationException` if the connection is closed which is more specific than your throw of `Exception`. If you intend to do something about that, catch the more specific exception later on. Now, you're using exceptions as part of your program logic which is not good practice.

Comment: I concede your point, but it still throws out when im not sending the inner exception.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.It is being called by a main() method that is wrapped in a try/catch. it works when theres normal errors, but these that happen at midnight always go as unhandled. i dont unstand this

Comment: You need to post that code as well in order for us to be able to help you. You need to read up on exception handling and be more careful about NullRefs. Have a look at Resharper for instance, which is a plugin that among a lot of things could help you spot NullRefs at design time.